# Username uniqueness validation - Design Approach

Tags: algorithm, hash

This is a general design problem - I want to validate a username field for uniqueness when the user enters the value and tabs out. I do a Ajax validation and get a response from the server. This is all very standard. Now, what if I have a HUGE user database ? How to handle this situation ? I want to find if  a username "foozbarz" is present among 150Million usernames ?

1. Database queries are out of question [EDIT] - Read the username database once and populate the cache/hash for faster lookup (to clarify **Emil Vikström**'s point)
2. In memory databases wont help either
3. Keep an in-memory hash (or cache/memcache) to store all usernames - usernames can be easily hashed and lookup will be very fast. But there are some problems with this:
    a. Size of the hash - can we optimize so that we can reduce the hash size ?
    b. Hash/cache refresh frequencies (users might get added while we are validating)
4. Shard the username table based on some criteria (e.g.: A-B in table username_1 and so on) - **thanks piotrek** for this suggestion

Or, any other better approach ?

Comment: How fast is it to simply trying to insert it and let the database tell you it's unable to do so?

Answer (score 2):

why don't you simply partition the data? if you have/plan to have 150M+ users i assume you have/will have budget for this. if you are just starting (with 2k users) do it traditional way with simple indexed search on database. when you have so many users that you **observe** performance issues and **measure** that this is because of your database (and not e.g. www server) then you simply put another database. on the first one you will have users with name from a to m and rest on the other one. you may choose other criterion, like hash, to make data be balanced. when you need more you will add more databases. but if you don't have so many users right now, i advise you not to do any premature optimizations. there are many things that may become a bottleneck with this amount of data

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely right about doing some kind of hashing where you store the taken names and, obviously, not hashed means it's free.

What you shouldn't do is rely on that validation. There can be a lot of time between user pressing Register and user checking if name is free.

To be fair, you only have one issue here and that's consideration for whether you REALLY need to worry whether you will get 150 million users. Scalability is often an issue, but unless this happens over night, you can probably swap in a better solution before this happens.

Secondly, your worry about both users getting a THIS NAME IS FREE and then one taking it. First of all, the chances of that happening are pretty damn low. Secondly, the only ways I can think of ‘solving’ this in a way where user will never click OK with validated name and get a USERNAME TAKEN is to either
a) Remember what user validated last, store that, and if someone else registers that in a mean time, use AJAX to change the name field to taken and notify the user. Don't do this. A lot of wasted cycles and really too much effort to implement.
b) Lock usernames as user validates one, for a short period of time. This results in a lot of free usernames coming up as taken when they actually aren't. You probably don't want this either.

The easiest solution for this is to simply put hash things into the table as users actually click OK, but before doing that, check if the name exists again. If it does, just send the user back with USERNAME TAKEN. The chances of someone racing someone else for a name are really, really slim and I doubt anyone will make a big fuss over how your validator (which did its job, the name was free at the point of checking) ‘lied’ to the user.

Basically your only issue is how you want to store the nicknames.

Answer (score 1):

Your #1 criteria is flawed because this is exactly what you have a database system for: to store and manage data. Why do you even have a table with usernames if you're not going to read it?

The first thing to do is improving the database system by adding an index, preferably a `HASH` index if your database system supports it. You will have a hard time writing anything near the performance of this yourself.

If this is not enough, you must start scaling your database, for example by building a clustered database or by partitioning the table into multiple sub-tables.

What I think is a fair thing to do is implement caching in front of the database, but for single names. Not all usernames will have a collision attempt, so you may cache the small subset where the collisions typically happen. A simple algorithm for checking the collision status of USER:

1. Check if USER exist in your cache. If it does:

   1. Set a "last checked" timestamp for USER inside the cache
   2. You are done and USER is a collision
2. Check the database for USER. If it does exist:

   1. Add USER to the cache
   2. If the cache is full (all X slots is used), remove the least recently used username from the cache (or the Y least recently used usernames, if you want to minimize cache pruning).
   3. You are done and USER is a collision
3. If it didn't match the cache or the db, you are done and USER is NOT a collision.

You will of course still need a UNIQUE contraint in your database to avoid race conditions.

Comment: I will read the USER table. But not always (as you correctly pointed out in your solution) - what I meant was that after reading the DB, I would populate a local cache that would speed up the validation

Answer (score 0):

If you're going the traditional route you could use an appropriate index to improve the database lookup.

You could also try using something like ElasticSearch which has very low latency lookups on large data sets.

Comment: Going to a database and querying 150Mil+ records (without sharding) is VERY costly even with the best possible index.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 150M+ users, you will have to have in place some function that:

1. Checks that the user exists, and signals if not found
2. Verifies the password is correct, and signals if it is not
3. Retrieves the user's data

This problem you will have, and will have to solve it. In all likelihood with something akin to a user's query. Even if you heavily rely on sessions, still you will have the problem of "finding session X among many from a 150M+ pool", which is structurally identical to "finding user X among many from a 150M+ pool".

Once you solve the bigger problem, the problem you now have is just its step #1.

So I'd check out a scalable database solution (possibly a NoSQL one), and implement the "availability check" using that.

You might end with a

```
retrieveUserData(user, password = None)
```

which returns the user info if user and password are valid and correct. For the availability check, you would send no password, and expect an UserNotFound exception if the username is available.

Comment: I am not doing password validation. Just checking VERY QUICKLY if a username already exists and displaying error if it does. No sessions are involved and I am not logging in anyone.

Comment: Yes, of course. What I was saying was, you can do this with the same function which you would need in any case to handle 150M+ users. You might do an existence-only test by implementing something like a Bloom filter (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter), but I don't see the need, and I'm not sure it would really be quicker than the database solution which, for 150M+ users, you'd need anyway.